# Why doesn't COALESCE work with RowFilter?

Tags: sql, wpf, coalesce, isnull, rowfilter

I'm developing a small application in WPF. I have a `ListBox` named `NameListBox` whose `ItemsSource` property is set to a `DataView`, and thus displays a list of customer names. The name is composed of 3 parts: `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, and `LastName`. I have used a converter to display the full name of customer in the list. Everything works fine (and I think this level of detail is enough to get the overall picture).

Now I want to enable **filtering** on the `NameListBox` such that the list should only displat those customer names that contain the text entered in the `TextBox` named `CustomerNameSearchBox`.

By searching on the Internet I came across `RowFilter` property of `DataView` - and also played with that a little. Now when I tried

```
private void CustomerNameSearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //((DataView)NameListBox.ItemsSource).RowFilter = @"COALESCE(FirstName+' '+MiddleName+' '+LastName, COALESCE(FirstName+' '+LastName, COALESCE(FirstName, LastName))) LIKE '%" + CustomerNameSearchBox.Text + @"%'";
    ((DataView)NameListBox.ItemsSource).RowFilter = @"ISNULL(FirstName+' '+MiddleName+' '+LastName, ISNULL(FirstName+' '+LastName, ISNULL(FirstName, LastName))) LIKE '%" + CustomerNameSearchBox.Text + @"%'";
}
```

This thing **gave me expected results**. But wait.. there's something strange here!!!

As you can see, the structure of both lines is the same - only `COALESCE` in place of `ISNULL`. But when I uncomment the first line (and comment out the second) it does't work!!!! **It throws an exception at runtime at that line saying `"The expression contains undefined function call COALESCE()."`!!!!**

Though `ISNULL` serves my purpose at this moment, I'm really curious to know why this exception happens. Moreover, even a simple thing like

```
(...).RowFilter = @"COALESCE(FirstName,'')";
```

doesn't seem to work!!!! (It means its more than just a syntactical problem)

Can anyone explain me about this behavior?? 
Thanks in advance.

Tags : WPF SQL COALESCE ISNULL RowFilter

Comment: What columns is the table made up of?

Answer (score 1):

The Rowfilter isn't SQL as such and has a limited scope of functionality

[MSDN: Expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)